# Как разрешить использовать только значения enum в TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы

подскажите как можно разрешить присваивать переменной только значения из enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнови тайпскрипт до 5й версии - там это одно из изменений.

Для более ранних версий - вроде никак.

---

Смотрим на переменную `y`:

- [4.9.5 - ok](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAyhAuALKBvAUFKBBKBeKAjAAwA0GUAQnlAEynkDC1AzPQL5poA2w8UAHgC5YCZPjhIAdFm68oAT2ESxhIkVl8AXktHViaIA)
- [5.0.2 - Type '100' is not assignable to type 'Smth'.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyhAuALKBvAUFKBBKBeKAjAAwA0GUAQnlAEynkDC1AzPQL5poA2w8UAHgC5YCZPjhIAdFm68oAT2ESxhIkVl8AXktHViaIA)

```
enum Smth {
  A = 10,
  B = 20,
  C = 30,
}

let x: Smth = Smth.A
let y: Smth = 100
let z: Smth = 10
```

Comment: Ну я установил последнюю версию, вопрос именно в том как это должно записываться

Comment: @davinchi59. [так же, как раньше](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyhAuALKBvAUFKBBKBeKAjAAwA0GUAQnlAEynkDC1AzPQL5poA2w8UAHgC5YCZPjhIAdFm68oAT2ESxhIkSgB6DVAAq8gA7AoAcmJFjUAJYBnKCAD2fAIbXrlgOYgnAIx5R49v4GRsbKxpKyfABeSqLUxGhAA).